# Javascript workson mac but not on live server (linux)

Tags: javascript, server

i have a problem.
my js function works fine on my mac, but when i upload it on the server, it doesn't work.
How is this possible?
all files are correctly located...

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {

var url="http://www.****.com/***/summer.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
$.each(json.summer,function(i,item){

$('<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center portfolioItemWrapper single-project">' +
'<div class="portfolioItem">' +
'<div class="effect imageWrapper">' + 
'<img src="images/genre/'+item.genre+'.jpg" alt="third">' +
'<div class="caption">' +
'<h4 class="oswald">' + item.name + '</h4>' +
'<p class="serifItalic">' + item.subtitel + ' </p>' + 
'<a href="single-project.html"><span class="moreText"> + </span></a>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>'
).appendTo('#betriebe');
});
});
});
  </script>
```

And here the div where the content appears (but only on the mac, not when i call it from the server...)

```
<div class="row gallery js-isotope" id="betriebe" data-isotope-options='{ "itemSelector": ".portfolioItemWrapper"}'>


        </div>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: That `http://` in `url` worries me—you might be unintentionally running into the cross-origin restriction.

Comment: you think i must change the var url? I tried with xxx, but nothing chanced... :-(

Comment: check console for error , is jquery loaded?

Comment: yes, jquery is loaded...

Comment: You should use debugger and check if you are getting expected json data..

Comment: @Amitesh you are right. i don't geht the son data. But why not? if i call the url, i get the json-data. but if i call the url in the website i don't get the son data.... Someone know why?
So i must make a own son data, and i can not call my data from the database. :-S

Comment: @user3690260 you need to check network tab of debugger and see the response/status. it might be forbidden if it is cross-origin request.

Comment: @Amitesh you are right. It was this problem. now i get the data from a php file in my database, and it is ok. BIG THANKS TO EVERYONE